# checked = "checked " stops working when I add ngModel in mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

My mat-checkbox's checked = "checked" stops working when I add an ngModel to it.

This will work.

```
<mat-checkbox name="BlackBeard" ngModel checked = "checked"> Zehahaha? </mat-checkbox>
```

This will not work.

```
<mat-checkbox name="BlackBeard" ngModel checked = "checked"> Zehahaha? </mat-checkbox>
```

Note : I require a solution that is generic. I want to use it in a scenario, where I am dynamically generating checkboxes. Although binding it to vairiables is a solution, i want one where i dont have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

your ngModel represent the value to your input.

if you are using ngmodel you need to handle the ngmodel value from your ts like

```
<mat-checkbox name="BlackBeard" [(ngModel)]="checkthis"> Zehahaha? </mat-checkbox>
```

in your ts file, you need to declare checkthis as boolean and assign a boolean value to it whenever you required as per your logic as

```
  checkthis:boolean = true;
```

this will make your checkbox checked.

check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrnhq8?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.ts)

Comment: I need a general answer. What if i have multiple checkboxes? what do i do if, i am generating checkboxes dynamically? I need something that is based on front end.

Comment: even if you want to generate checkboxes dynamically ngModel is a good way for handling the value of your checkboxes. there are many examples online for using ngModel as well as using checked.  for a dynamic and multiple you can use both. you need to pass a boolean value to your ngmodel or checked = "checked" in your checked attribute. if you use Ngmodel it will store value throughout.